# Store maximum records in query_cache with MySql

Tags: mysql

I have a product table which contain 400 000 records.

On my server I have enabled the query_cache_type. It is ON now, but I am not getting a better performance.

Is there a way that I can increase the number of records can store in the cache? I have already set the query_cache_limit   to 1 024 000 and query_cache_size to    2 048 000.

Below is my configuration for query cache.

```
binlog_rows_query_log_events    OFF
ft_query_expansion_limit    20
have_query_cache    YES
long_query_time 10.000000
query_alloc_block_size  8192
query_cache_limit   1024000
query_cache_min_res_unit    4096
query_cache_size    2048000
query_cache_type    ON
query_cache_wlock_invalidate    OFF
query_prealloc_size 8192
slow_query_log  OFF
slow_query_log_file /rdsdbdata/log/slowquery/mysql-slowquery.log
```

Are any modifications are needed? I have 400 000 records to store in cache.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Can you please tell me which variables i need to modify ? Give me a name and it's value i need to put it.

Comment: 2048000  does it consider this as Bytes or KB ?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález , its fine Can you please tell me that does it consider 2048000 this value as Bytes or kb ? ?

Answer (score 0):

The most relevant variables in [configuration](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache-configuration.html) include:

- [have_query_query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_have_query_cache): it merely reports whether the server binary has been compiled with the query cache module.
- [query_cache_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_query_cache_size): it's used to disable cache (`0`) or set its maximum size (a byte number that's multiple of 1024). You have `2048000` what means 1,9 MB. You should increase it to a few dozen MB (not more, it's normally not good to have some hundred MBs).
- [query_cache_limit](http://query_cache_limit) prevents caching of large datasets (this is the upper limit of cached results, in bytes). You have the default value of 1024000 (1MB) which I guess is fine.
- [query_cache_min_res_unit](http://query_cache_min_res_unit) is the minimum size of cache blocks (in bytes). You have the default 4096 byte value, which should be fine to start. You can reduce it if you happen to have many queries with tiny sizes.

... and last but not least:

- [query_cache_type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_query_cache_type): it determines what queries to cache and allows provides a way to to disallow cache temporarily. You have the default value of `ON` that means *Cache all cacheable query results except for those that begin with `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE`*.

You can also check the Qcache_... status variables to see how things are going on:

```
SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Qcache%';
```

Comment: Can you please what are the values i need to set  ?   as i have told i have 4 lacs records to fetch.

Comment: That's like asking how large your SD Card needs to be, it depends on what you need to store. What do Qcache_... status variables reveal about your cache usage? (I'm not familiar with *lacs record* anyway.)

Comment: @PunitGajjar As you can see, using Indian measurements causes misunderstandings. Please don't use them. The case is just 400k records.

Comment: If your query returns 400,000 rows and `query_cache_limit` is `1,024,000` bytes you only have 2 bytes left for each row to be cached (and if you eventually run `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Qcache%'` you'll possibly find your query does not get cached). But caching is the right tool only if those 400,000 are hard to calculate—transferring them to the client is always going to be kind of slow.